# How CopyOnWriteArrayList is replaces the original Array with the copy and when does it happen?

Tags: java

As per the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` JavaDoc:

> A thread-safe variant of java.util.ArrayList in which all mutative
>   operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh
>   copy of the underlying array.

Is each thread working on its own local copy always after the mutation?

I think the copy should replace the original array. How is the copy replaced with the original array for other thread to use and at what stage does this happen?

Comment: It isn't "merged back to the main array."  The data structure has a pointer to the array that is changed to point to the new array.

Comment: You have the source code. Why not look at it, to find how it works?

Comment: yes @Andreas, I saw the source code after posting and before posting too. But, was not clear completely. The add method is already locking before the operation and unlocking once the add operation is done. Want to confirm why add is working on a copy instead of the main array. I think the reason is that the iterator works on the main array and if add is not done on the copy, then it may throw CME. Kindly suggest if my understanding is correct?

Comment: You are correct. You can't make the copy visible to other threads until it is complete, including the new value. --- Note that you question is misphrased. There is no "merge" going on, and there is no "main" array. The updated copy will *replace* the original array, once the copy-and-update operation is complete, at which time all other threads will see it.

Comment: @Andreas, I have updated the question

Comment: There is no "main array."  There is only the current array.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the set implementation its creating the new Object array with existing element and after operation replacing  the new array

```
/**
 * Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
 * specified element.
 *
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E set(int index, E element) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        Object[] elements = getArray();//creating the new array with ting vaue
        E oldValue = elementAt(elements, index);

        if (oldValue != element) {
            int len = elements.length;
            Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len);
            newElements[index] = element;
            setArray(newElements);//replacing the old array
        } else {
            // Not quite a no-op; ensures volatile write semantics
            setArray(elements);
        }
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

same way add and remove method implemented 
since all these methods are thread safe so suppose if two threads working on add method then both thread have its own copy of elements

from doc:

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException. The iterator will not reflect additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was created.